# Is there anyway to count the number of values in a Word Graph?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to get the total number of values in the graph in Word. Ultimately, I want to be able to change the color of the last bar of my bar graph, so getting the number of values is a way. If there are any other ways to get that last value, please do post it here, it will be appreciated.

I need to be able to do this using Word VBA. Can anybody help me out? Thank you, guys

Comment: What does the graph look like? Does it have multiple series or do you just need to count the values in one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Chart` object, which for instance can be retrieved from an `InlineShape` as follows:

```
Dim shp As InlineShape
Dim cht As Chart
Set shp = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
Set cht = shp.Chart
```

You can count the `Values` collection of the chart's first `Series`, e.g.:

```
MsgBox UBound(cht.SeriesCollection(1).Values)
```

Comment: That's so helpful. Thanks!